# Inconsistent behaviour with ModelState validation asp.net core api

Tags: api, asp.net-core, bad-request

I get an inconsistent behaviour when asp.net core api validates objects and when I manually add model errors and invoke BadRequest(ModelState)

As an example, I have these 2 endpoints in my controller

```
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult Post(MyModel model)
{
    return Ok();
}

[HttpPost]
[Route("test")]
public IActionResult OtherPost()
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("field", "error");
    return BadRequest(ModelState);
}
```

and MyModel is:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    [MinLength(10)]
    public string MyProperty { get; set; }
}
```

When I invoke the first endpoint with an empty body I don't need to validate ModelState because the framework is going to do it automatically and gives this response:

```
{
"errors":{"MyProperty":["The MyProperty field is required."]},
"title":"One or more validation errors occurred.",
"status":400,
"traceId":"80000005-0000-ff00-b63f-84710c7967bb"
}
```

With the second controller I get this:

```
{"field":["error"]}
```

Am I using the wrong method to add errors to ModelState or it is an known problem?

Comment: I believe the framework might be calling AddModelError (string key, Exception exception, Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.ModelBinding.ModelMetadata metadata) instead.  Try adding that in your code instead of just a text error.

Comment: what should their values be?

Comment: I was wrong.  See https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/issues/6077 a detailed discussion.

Comment: @Andrea is your controller inheriting from Controller or ApiController?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

1. If you prefer to validating the model state by yourself and expect a exactly same result as the failure message of `ApiController` binding, you could make it as below :

```
    public IActionResult Other2Post()
    {
        ModelState.AddModelError("field", "error");
        var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState)
        {
            Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
        };

        var traceId = Activity.Current?.Id ?? HttpContext.TraceIdentifier;
        problemDetails.Extensions["traceId"] = traceId;

        var result = new BadRequestObjectResult(problemDetails);
        result.ContentTypes.Add("application/problem+json");
        result.ContentTypes.Add("application/problem+xml");
        return result;
    }
```

2. Or if you don't need the `traceId`, you could simply return a `BadRequest` of `ValidationProblemDetails`:

```
    ModelState.AddModelError("field", "error");
    var problemDetails = new ValidationProblemDetails(ModelState)
    {
        Status = StatusCodes.Status400BadRequest,
    };
    return BadRequest(problemDetails);
```

Demo :

[image]

For more information, see [the related source code here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/0d6e0637afa47be74864514d0378c20951306874/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/DependencyInjection/ApiBehaviorOptionsSetup.cs#L106-L120) and [here](https://github.com/aspnet/AspNetCore/blob/master/src/Mvc/Mvc.Core/src/Infrastructure/ProblemDetailsClientErrorFactory.cs#L48-L52).

Comment: Thank you, that is what I was looking for

Comment: Thank you so much. Thank you for the links as well. This is making more sense. It was a shock to discover that my errors weren't being returned as errors and it made for some messy consumer side code for validation management.

Answer (score 18):

You could use

```cs
public IActionResult Post(SomeModel model)
{
    ModelState.AddModelError("key", "message");
    return ValidationProblem(ModelState);
}
```

This code produces similar response, without traceId only.
*UPD1*: For asp.net core 3.1 it returns `traceId`

Comment: This is the easiest and best response.

Comment: Worked quite nicely for me as well.

Comment: In ASP.NET Core 6, it's sufficient with `return ValidationProblem();`, it will use `ControllerBase.ModelState` by default.

Answer (score 2):

ApiController performs automatic model state validation and returns a response in case of an error.

If you want similar behavior, you can disable the automatic validation and response:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.Configure<ApiBehaviorOptions>(options =>
    {
        options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
    });
}
```

[See here](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/disable-automatic-model-state-validation-in-asp-net-core-2-1/) for more info. Hope it helps!

Comment: You could disable model state validation by just removing [ApiController] attribute.